# Using N-Grams to search within a table of string Xcode, swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, n-gram

Below is my code for the current search, right now it only checks string by string. How do I implement ngram into it? This code checks an array of strings compared to what the user types in on the front end. It generates results with that string.

ngram is a solution i found online for what i need. However, what i want is the ability for users to search in the array without the use of spaces, say the array is "I love sushi and popcorn,...." and the user searches "I love popcorn" the array which consist of the string "I love sushi and popcorn" will not show up. However, I want it to be.

One option is to write a function that puts each string seperated by space into another array and have the search function run through a loop in that array and do this for each other strings. However, I find this inefficient.

Please let me know if there are other solutions. Thanks

```
 func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // filter results
        // reload table
        let searchString:String = searchController.searchBar.text!
        self.dataToDisplay =  self.sampleData.filter({ (dataString:String) -> Bool in


        let match = dataString.range(of: searchString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)   

        if match != nil {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    })

    self.pdfArrSearch = self.pdfArr.filter({ (dataString:String) -> Bool in


    let match = dataString.range(of: searchString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
    if match != nil {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/rxwei/CoreLinguistics/blob/master/Sources/LangKit/LanguageModeling/Ngrams.swift

Comment: @SachinVas Could you tell me how will I call the necessary functions? Im not sure as im new to ios developing

Comment: Just import those files into your project. `searchString.ngrams( 3, form: .word)`

Comment: @SachinVas Not as simple, I got error when I put 

let match = searchString.ngrams( 3, form: .word)

Comment: The imported files gives me errors too

Comment: @SachinVas what do you think of Regex?